# In query in hibernate?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using hibernate and i am able to get the list of employeees having salary as 2000 using this.

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("salary", 2000));
List results = cr.list();
```

Now i want to get the employees having salary as 2000  and 3000 .

How i can use `in query` in hibernate using criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Restrictions.in i.e.

```
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
        List<Integer> salaryList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        salaryList.add(2000);
        salaryList.add(3000);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.in("salary", salaryList));
        List results = cr.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Friend you can use this

```
   List list =session.createCriteria(Employee.class).
add(Restrictions.between("salary",2000,3000);
```

This between method very usefull